# Мне нужно создать функцию которая будет брать из списка объекты класса и записывать всех их в файл

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, файлы, классы

Мне нужно создать функцию которая будет брать из списка объекты класса и записывать всех их в jsonlines файл, файл уже существует в нем список ключей записан мне нужно чтоб он брал объекты из этого списка:

```
users = [User(**item) for item in result]
```

сам список виглядит так:

```
[<__main__.User object at 0x106ec7340>, <__main__.User object at 0x106ec73a0>, <__main__.User object at 0x106ec72e0>, <__main__.User object at 0x106ec7400>, <__main__.User object at 0x106ec7520>, <__main__.User object at 0x106ec75e0>, <__main__.User object at 0x106ec7610>, <__main__.User object at 0x106ec7670>, <__main__.User object at 0x106ec7700>, <__main__.User object at 0x106ec7790>, <__main__.User object at 0x106ec7820>, <__main__.User object at 0x106ec78b0>, <__main__.User object at 0x106ec7940>, <__main__.User object at 0x106ec79d0>, <__main__.User object at 0x106ec7a60>, <__main__.User object at 0x106ec7af0>]
```

и записал их в файл вот функция которую я написал но она не принимает объекты:

```
def users_2_file():
    with jsonlines.open('data.jsonl', 'a') as jsonlines_f:
        jsonlines_f.write(users)
```

но одно примечание нужно чтоб он записывал эти объекты чтоб в файл они имели вид списка ключей где каждый объект выглядит как-то так:

```
{"name": "Mary", "time_created": 1665333931, "gender": "female", "age": 18, "city": "NY", "last_name": "Smith", "premium": null, "ip": "192.168.0.110", "birth_day": "01.01", "balance": 55.99832723139716, "user_id": 8508}
```

вот класс из которого создаются объекты:

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, user_id, name, time_created, gender, last_name, premium, city, age, ip, birth_day, balance):
        self.user_id = user_id
        self.name = name
        self.time_created = time_created
        self.gender = gender
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.premium = premium
        self.city = city
        self.age = age
        self.ip = ip
        self.birth_day = birth_day
        self.balance = balance
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import jsonlines


class User:
    def __init__(self, user_id, name, time_created):
        self.user_id = user_id
        self.name = name
        self.time_created = time_created

    def __str__(self):
        return(f'{self.user_id} {self.name} {self.time_created}')

# создаем список
users = [
    User(7, 'a', '2022-11-10 10:00'),
    User(12, 'b', '2022-11-10 22:19'),
]

# сохраняем в файл. вместо объекта отдаем словарь со свойствами
with jsonlines.open('data.jsonl', 'w') as jsonlines_f:
    for x in users:
        jsonlines_f.write(vars(x))

# удаляем список
users = []

# прочитаем его из файла
with jsonlines.open('data.jsonl') as reader:
    for x in reader:
        users.append(User(**x))

# посмотрим что получилось
for x in users:
    print(x)

# 7 a 2022-11-10 10:00
# 12 b 2022-11-10 22:19
```